# What is causing my thread to call stored procedure twice?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, multithreading, stored-procedures

I'm seeing a very strange issue with my code.

Here is the thread creation code (in Home.aspx.cs)

```
WindowsIdentity current_identity = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
HttpContext ctx = HttpContext.Current;

Thread worker = new Thread(delegate()
{
    WindowsImpersonationContext context = current_identity.Impersonate();
    HttpContext.Current = ctx;
    MyClass.MyMethod();
    context.Undo();
});
worker.CurrentCulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
worker.IsBackground = true;
worker.Start();
```

In MyClass.aspx.cs, I have the method that the thread calls:

```
public static void MyMethod()
{
    if (cache["MyList"] == null)
    {
        cache["MyList"] = MyList.Get();
    }
}
```

cache is a `Dictionary<string, object>` that we created that lives in `HttpContext.Current.Session`. MyList.Get() is basically a factory method that eventually calls a stored procedure to populate MyList with data.

In MyClass.aspx.cs, I also have a property:

```
public static MyList MyList
{
    get
    {
        if (cache["MyList"]) == null) // Breakpoint here
        {
             cache["MyList"] = MyList.Get();
        }
        return cache["MyList] as MyList;
    }
}
```

When I navigate to Home.aspx.cs, the worker thread is created and calls MyClass.MyMethod which invokes the stored procedure. I used SQL Profiler to make sure that the stored procedure is indeed executed. Next, I navigate to the page MyClass.aspx.cs. Now, my breakpoint which I set inside the getter for the property MyList is hit. I look at the cache and it only contains 3 items but it doesn't contain the entry with a key of "MyList".

The strange part is that maybe 30 seconds later to a minute, the cache would magically have 4 items. I look at SQL profiler and the same stored procedure got executed again.

My questions are:

1. What is causing cache not to have the entry with key of "MyList" until much later? Is it because the thread hasn't finished?
2. What is causing my stored procedure to run the 2nd time?

Comment: What is your Session State Provider?

Comment: I don't think it is related to your problem but `HttpContext.Current` is going to get cleaned up on you if you are using it in a separate thread and you are not doing a `worker.Join()` before the end of the page request.

Comment: @spender I have no clue. Can you please tell me the steps I need in order to find out?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178586.aspx

Comment: According to web.config, we use "InProc" as our sessionState mode.